# CSS: selecting a td with a background image

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm working in Volusion and have this horrendous combinations of selectors:

```
div#content_area table tr td table tr td table tr td, div#content_area table tr td table tr td table tr, div#content_area table tr td table tr td table
```

Now, I have to target the first td of the first row in a table but only if that td has a background image of Divider_Horizontal.gif.

I'd settle just for the first td of the first tr with a background. As this image is a background image set on the td, I can't control the height via the normal means because Volusion uses VB script converted to asp. Horrendous. I can't read the script as it gets garbled.

So, I was just going to use an overriding css declaration to add height to the specific td but I'm not getting how to specify the "only with a background" part.

I could also use jquery, but even then, I'm not sure how to spec the actual content part as it's not really html and hitting the attribute of a td doesn't seem to be working.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `filter` method:

```
$('div#content_area table tr td:first').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('background-image') === 'url(Divider_Horizontal.gif)'
}).foo()
```

Comment: thanks. That led me to the solution of CMS woes:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    (function($) {
    $('div#content_area table tbody tr td     form#MainForm.search_results_section table tbody tr td table tbody tr td').height(10);
 
    })(jQuery);

    });

    </script>

Comment: @kellyjohnson You are welcome, for selecting an element by id `$('#id')` is sufficient.